# Auxiliares HTML vs auxiliares de marcação

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, html-helpers

Aparentemente os auxiliares HTML e os de marcação, conseguem realizar as mesmas funções, como este exemplo que encontrei na [documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers):

**Auxiliares HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizo" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBorFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Auxiliares de marcação**

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" class="form-horizo">
    <h4>Create new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Realmente me parece que eles fazem as mesmas coisas, apenas com sintaxes diferentes, então me surgiu as seguintes dúvidas:

- Tem alguma diferença em o que um auxiliar HTML e um auxiliar de marcação pode fazer que o outro não?
- Existe alguma recomendação, ou boa prática sobre qual deles devo usar?
- Em questão de performance, algum deles se destaca, ou são equivalentes?

Comment: Coloque código sempre como texto formatando com `Ctrl+K` ou clicando no botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: @Isac Na verdade a intenção era apenas adicionar uma pequena parte do exemplo na documentação da Microsoft (Que utiliza essas imagens), vou escrever o código então.

Comment: Podem me informar por favor o motivo dos negativos, para que eu possa editar a pergunta para se adequar? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tem alguma diferença em o que um auxiliar HTML e um auxiliar de marcação pode fazer que o outro não?

Não. Os dois foram feitos para funcionar independentemente.

> Existe alguma recomendação, ou boa prática sobre qual deles devo usar?

Não. Mas mantenha um padrão, seus colegas de código agradecerão. De qualquer maneira, a segunda forma é a nova e os possíveis problemas dos HTML Helpers foram solucionados.

Além a forma nova é mais parecida com HTML, o que torna o código bem mais padronizado

> Em questão de performance, algum deles se destaca, ou são equivalentes?

Nenhum se destaca. Nem teria como, uma vez que o objetivo dos dois é gerar HTML. O que pode acontecer é mudar o tempo de "compilação", mas aí é outro caso e a diferença deve ser ínfima.

Comment: hahaha agora consigo votar kkk